# python subprocess running c++ task reading file error

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing, subprocess

I have a c++ task which reads a file and process it:

```
// A.m.cpp
    std::string filename = "myfile.txt";
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    std::ifstream file1(filename.c_str());
    std::string line1;
    while(getline(file1, line1)){
      // process some logic 
    }
    
    for(;;){
       file.getline(buffer);
       if (file.eof()) break;
      // process some other logic
    }
```

and I have a python script to set test data and run the task:

```
import unittest
   def test_A():
       file='myfile.txt'
       with open(file, 'w') as filetowrite:
           filetowrite('testdata')

       subprocess.run(["A.tsk"])
```

However, when I run the python script and executing the c++ task, the first while loop works, but the for loop just break bc of eof here:

```
for(;;){
       file.getline(buffer); // buffer is "testdata"
       if (file.eof()) break;  // it breaks even buffer is "testdata"
      // process some other logic
    }
```

I printed `buffer` and it has "testdata", however it just breaks in the next line so it did not got processed which is not what i want. However, if i do not use python `subprocess` to run it nor use Python to set test data, and just `echo testdata >> myfile.txt`, then compile `A.m.cpp` and run `A.tsk` manually, it did not break in the for loop and process "testdata" successfully. What is wrong with `subprocess`? Why does it trigger `eof` even `buffer` has content?

Comment: `testdata` isn't followed by a newline so `eof` being set after `getline` isn't unexpected? (though `filetowrite('testdata')` doesn't seem to be valid python)

Comment: ohh, you are right, then i think the problem becomes why `echo testdata >> myfile.txt` works but `filetowrite('testdata')` does not work.. I guess `echo` will append `\n` at the end?

Comment: does `filetowrite('testdata')` even run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the .eof() break after the processing:

```
for(;;){
    file.getline(buffer); // buffer is "testdata"
    // process some other logic
    if (file.eof()) break;
}
```

You'll want to process the data even if EOF is hit after it's read. Note that this can give you empty strings in buffer, so you might want to handle that case in the processing code.

You'll also want to change the python line to:

```
filetowrite.write("testdata\n")
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that it's because of the differences between `echo testdata >> myfile.txt` and `filetowrite('testdata')`.  But I think I should not change c++ code since this is production and I should only change my tests. So I guess `echo test >> myfile.txt` will append `\n` at the end so i should use `filetowrite('testdata\n')`?

Comment: @coder Yes, but use `filetowrite.write("testdata\n")`. You're trying to call a file object there, in your code.